# Sending emails to different addresses based on cell value

Tags: email, google-sheets

I'm trying to send emails based on cell values.

For example - When column D26 is selected as "Yes" it sends an email of the body of the spreadsheet to one user.

THEN, when column D51 on the SAME SHEET is selected as "Yes" it sends another email to another user.

THEN when a different column on the same document but different sheet is selected as "Approved" it sends a final email to another different user

It works when there is only 1 sendnotification script in place but I believe the script is overriding itself and not working when the other options are selected.

Comment: It might help to include your current script. You could use an IF or Switch block to do what you require.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of sending emails to one of two choices.

```
function battlingEmails()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('EmailDest');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    if(!rngA[i][5])
    {
      MailApp.sendEmail(rngA[i][rngA[i][2]-1], rngA[i][3], rngA[i][4])
      //Logger.log('Email: ' + rngA[i][rngA[i][2]-1] + 'Option: ' + rngA[i][2] + 'Subject: ' + rngA[i][3] + 'Body: ' + rngA[i][4]);
      sht.getRange(i+1,6).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Here's what the spreadsheet looks like:

[image]